# manually check if claims token is ok

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, token

I have a custom attribute where I manually wanna check if a claims token is valid. How do I do that?

```
public class AuthorizeClaimsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override bool UserAuthorized(IPrincipal user) {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("bearerToken");
        if (cookie != null) {
            //Check if token is valid, how?
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The token is created as follow:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", model.Username));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("IsAdmin", isAdmin.ToString()));

        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() {
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan)
        };

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

**Note: I cannot use the existing `Authorize` attribute. That´s why I need to check it manually.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to store the token alongside its username somewhere in a persistant data structure

For example, when you create the Identity store the `model.UserName` & the `accessToken` in a a database of your choice.

Then, when you want to check your `cookie` you can re-open your database and query for it and take the appropriate action.

Also, adding that date in the database will also help you keep the size of it down resulting in faster searches, i.e. if your token only lasts for 3 months, delete the old ones as part of maintenance

Comment: So I need to save the token somewhere? Is that the only way of validate i manually?

Comment: When you create `identity` store `var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);` alongside `identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", model.Username));` in a persistent data structure. Then when checking `cookie` you have something to compare it too.